# Google Analytics - Track Events - Apostrophe Issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've set up GA event tracking on my hyperlinks, they are all working ok appart from page names which contain an apostrophe.

So if my page is called What's On, this is causing a problem.

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Navigation', 'top', 'What's On', 5, true]);" title="What's On" href="index.aspx?articleid=1234">What's On</a>
```

Has anyone come across this issue? Obviously the apostrophe is causing the tracking for this particular link to fail.

Is it possible to escape it?

I've looked at string replace but not sure if that will work in this situation.

thanks

ps it's not really an option to just call the page "Whats On" as this issue affects many pages in the CMS.

**Update**

It's ok I've managed to get it to work by reversing the quotes.

```
<a onclick='_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Navigation", "top", "What's On", 5, true]);' title="What's On" href="index.aspx?articleid=1234">What's On</a>
```

Not sure if this is the best way or not but it's tracking these pages now.

Comment: Yes that's the best way to fix it.  You where confusing the web browser (or maybe JavaScript not sure which) the other way everything in side ' or " gets sent, so when you have a ' inside a group of 's it doesn't know what to send.  Changing it to " fixes the problem.

Comment: My original javascript code was taken straight from the google example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']); They obviously havent thought about these links being generated from a CMS!

Comment: Yup but it doesn't have a ' in it does it :)

Comment: I know, that why i said they haven't thought about links generated from a cms which might have an apostrophe

Comment: You never know what CMS's do.  Its best to be prepared :)

Comment: String values must be delimited with single or double quotes. So if you use single quotes to delimit the string, you must escape the single quote if you want to have one in your string.  This isn't a failure on GA's end. This is how the javascript syntax works. And any other programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is why your solution works (Added in the event anyone sees this in the future):

The push function takes 6 variables. Lets look at a couple of them:

```
var category = 'Navigation'; 
var action = 'top' ;
var labels = 'What's On' ;
var values = 5

push(["_trackEvent", category ,action ,labels , values , true]);
```

A string is surrounded by a ' or " while a number isn't.   By having a ' inside of two 's the system doesn't understand what you mean.  To fix that you can add an [escape string](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp), or do like you did and surround them with " instead.  The drawback to using the escape string method is that the escape string will also be sent to GA.

```
var labels = 'What\'s On' ;
var labels = "What's On" ;
```

Both of those would work.  \ is escaping the '.